# installing ubuntu on windows 8

Tags: installation, 12.10, windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed UEFI Supported Windows 8 system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system)

I have a windows 8 preloaded computer(an Acer aspire m touch) and no luck with the shift+restart method does not bring up ufei settings. Please  help me install Ubuntu 64 bit

Answer (score 1):

I've recently gone through this process on a Sony Vaio T13 preloaded with Windows 8, in short I cheated and installed Ubuntu on a virtual machine (VirtualBox) which was a straightforward process detailed description [here](http://www.ianhopkinson.org.uk/2013/01/windows-8-and-ubuntu-12-10-on-a-sony-vaio-t13-laptop/).

Answer (score 0):

Did you change your booting drive to your CD drive in your BIOS?I think it will work after you have set it right.